# My app is running on emulator perfectly. But when i installed it on my android device it does not run

Tags: java, android-studio, android-emulator

**My app is running on emulator perfectly. But when i installed it on my android device it does not run. There are some errors coming in Logcat but they are not effecting on app in emulator**

2019-11-20 20:44:04.457 1776-2434/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8

2019-11-20 20:44:18.501 1776-2434/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2019-11-20 20:44:18.501 1776-2434/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2019-11-20 20:44:18.756 2830-2830/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Missing BluetoothAdapter
2019-11-20 20:44:19.126 16014-16014/com.example.timerapp E/xample.timerap: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2019-11-20 20:44:19.529 1776-2434/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2019-11-20 20:44:19.530 1776-2434/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2019-11-20 20:44:19.920 1791-2085/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-11-20 20:44:19.921 1791-2085/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2019-11-20 20:44:20.529 1776-2434/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2019-11-20 20:44:20.530 1776-2434/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8
2019-11-20 20:44:20.839 2830-2830/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/BeaconBle: Scan couldn't start for Places
2019-11-20 20:44:21.529 1776-2434/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: a: input svInfo.flags is 8
2019-11-20 20:44:21.529 1776-2434/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8

Comment: Take attention on " Missing BluetoothAdapter ", check your BT Adapter and permissions

Comment: Make sure you ask for Bluetooth permissions when your application starts at the beginning